# cifs mount oddity: adds directory with the name of the share?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, cifs

I am trying to mount a samba share on Ubuntu using `cifs` (either by an `fstab` entry or by just using the mount command).

My share is `//hostname/data`

My mountpoint is `/mnt/project1`

I mount using

`sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,gid=123,uid=123,vers=3.0,mfsymlinks,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0600,dir_mode-0700,username=myname //hostname/data/project1  /mnt/project1`

This works and I would expect to find the contents of `/data/project1/` on hostname in directory `/mnt/project1`

However, what I get instead is this: the directory `/data/project1/` contains a subdirectory data which then contains the contents of `/data/project1`

Why/how can this happen and how can I avoid it?

BTW, the samba share comes from a Synology NAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was my mistake really.

The mount actually works as intended, I was just confused from the wrong data being inside the mounted share.

So apparently, everything works as I expected, and - other than suggested in the other answer - it is indeed possible to mount a subdirectory and not just a whole share.